# Why is the volume "naturally" lower when playing movies?

Tags: windows-7, audio

There's an annoying difference in volume from playing movies vs. sound/music coming from Youtube videos and other various computer functions, like playing music, games, etc.

I've heard this has something to do with the extra audio channels that movies have within them, but not sure if that's what's happening.

And is there a way to rectify this, so that I don't have to change my system's volume so drastically when going to/from movies? Is there something I can do to overcome the hurdle of re-mixing/redirecting the extra audio channels into the two reference speakers and a subwoofer I have? Or is the only option some type of equalization?

NOTE
My audio setup is and HDMI output from my 6950 card to a Yamaha 667 receiver, which feeds two Klipsch reference speakers and a BIC subwoofer.

Comment: I'd guess it has to do with *dynamic headroom*, the amount of audio compression, and allowance for very loud sounds like explosions.  I've noticed that digital soundtracks to have more consistent levels between movies than older analog soundtracks (on tape and laserdisc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The average volume is lower to make room for the big dynamic peaks that are common in movies. Explosions wouldn't be much fun if they were the same volume as whispers.

Personally I like having a large dynamic range when watching movies, but if you want to lessen the effect you can look for "dynamic compression" or "compressor" or something to that effect in your video player. If you're using VLC you can find it under Tools -> Effects and Filters -> Audio Effects -> Compressor. There's a pretty decent [article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression#Compressor_controls_and_features) that explains the various settings and terms involved.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Didn't know that, and I understand why that'd make complete sense. I feel a bit better about leaving it like it is -- Thanks!